# Haskell binding for scala program

Tags: haskell

Could you please let me know whether or not it's possible to write Haskell bindings for Scala?

Thanks in advance for any examples.

Comment: I know of no such thing, but probably there's been some attempt towards Haskell<->Java/JVM interop. Have you tried googling for that?

Comment: Frege (https://github.com/Frege/frege) is a dialect of Haskell that targets the JVM. The language supported is very close to that compiled by GHC, but the FFI interfaces with JVM classes instead of native code.

Answer (score 2):

Frege (https://github.com/Frege/frege) is a dialect of Haskell that targets the JVM. The language supported is very close to that compiled by GHC, but the FFI interfaces with JVM classes instead of native code.

Comment: Actually, GHC compiles much, much more than Frege. Frege is in the process of reaching Haskell 2010 compatibility. This means that many GHC features that go far beyond Haskell 2010 are not supported.

Comment: @Ingo: Quite right. I should've mentioned compatibility with Haskell2010 not GHC. Sorry for the misleading answer.